# Communication between Flutter widgets

Tags: flutter, bloc

Flutter widget update pattern is a little bit confusing when coming from "old/classic" win32.

For instance :
I have a widget "button" => I click on it => I update a cell in a widget "datatable".

With classic API (VCL, Net Forms, ...) I get the address of button (by name, id, ...) and call directly

```
datatable_address.cell[x,y] = new_value;
```

I understand that I have to use setState() but do I need to create an "event" in Datatable (to run its setState()) and fire up this event from my button ?

(BloC seems pretty close to Qt signals)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is composition vs aggregation. The widgets themselves are immutable so you can't change the value inside a widget.

What you can do is create a new object with latest values. Flutter framework will take care of the rest. For example,

when you do setState in parent widget of both button as well as datatable, you build method of said widget is called. Now, you will create a new datatable object with updated cell values. Internally, flutter will handle this.

You can only do setState in State class which is not immutable which is linked to Stateful widget which themselves are immutable.

This architecture comes with its own set of problems like if you need to update some UI based on some button press, you will have to have the logic inside the common widget of both the affected widget and button. That's where Stream/Bloc comes into picture.